# call Ajax.AjaxMethod() from jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I convert 1.x ajax to jQuery type ajax? I am converting web form of .net 1.x to 4.0.

The old way...
(client side):

```
function myFunction(){
  AspxCodeBehind.myAjaxFunction(ajxCallBack)
}

function ajxCallBack(response){
  if (response.value != null) { alert(response.value); }
}

(server side, AspxCodeBehind.aspx.vb):
<Ajax.AjaxMethod()> _
Public Function myAjaxFunction() as String
  Return "Hello World"
End Function

The jquery way...
$().ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "???"  <--- This is the part not sure what 
    success: function(resp){
    }
  });
});
```

I don't see how I can call myAjaxFunction from jQuery. The url: is expecting a web method be it a web service or web page rather then a code behind method. 
Well, I can still use the old way without implementing jquery, but can anyone suggest the easiest way to achieve this by jquery.

TIA
Regards,
KK Gian

Answer (score 0):

ajax is fun:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "file.php"  <--- This is the file that the ajax will return relative to the current document
 success: function(response){
  alert("This is the response "+response);
 }
```

});

Comment: Thanks Coomie, I don't think you get my question right. I have no issue calling a php file though. I am in .net environment, and the web method is in code behind of aspx file (aspx.vb). Although I can expose the method by using [WebMethod], I still having issue of Shared (static) with session variable.

Comment: Try retagging this question to asp.net